# Get error "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator" on count within where clause

Tags: sql, oracle10g

This is an employee to dependent relationship. I am having trouble displaying only the employee who has more than one dependent. The line that should not be there is for emp_no 555555.

```
 SELECT emp_no, emp_name, dep_emp_no, dep_name, dep_relationship, trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(current_date, dep_date_of_birth)/12) "Age"
 FROM DEPENDENT d JOIN employee e ON e.emp_no=d.dep_emp_no
WHERE dep_date_of_birth=(SELECT MIN(DEP_DATE_OF_BIRTH) FROM DEPENDENT dd WHERE d.dep_emp_no=dd.dep_emp_no)


 EMP_NO EMP_NAME                       DEP_EM DEP_NAME             DEP_RELATI        Age
 ------ ------------------------------ ------ -------------------- ---------- ----------
 444444 Hickman, Ron                   444444 Amy                  DAUGHTER           22
 555555 Moore, Wayne                   555555 Sharon               SPOUSE             65
 111111 Li, Anna                       111111 Chris                SON                 8
```

This is what is giving me the error:

```
 SELECT emp_no, 
        emp_name, 
        dep_emp_no, 
        dep_name, 
        dep_relationship, 
        trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(current_date, dep_date_of_birth)/12) "Age"
   FROM DEPENDENT d 
   JOIN employee e ON e.emp_no=d.dep_emp_no
  WHERE dep_date_of_birth=(SELECT MIN(DEP_DATE_OF_BIRTH) 
                             FROM DEPENDENT dd 
                            WHERE d.dep_emp_no=dd.dep_emp_no)
 and where DEP_EMP_NO exists (select count(dep_emp_no) 
                                from dependent 
                              having count(dep_emp_no)>1 
                            group by dep_emp_no);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `and where DEP_EMP_NO` too much and a condition missing in the count. The following should work.

```
SELECT emp_no, 
       emp_name, 
       dep_emp_no, 
       dep_name, 
       dep_relationship, 
       trunc(MONTHS_BETWEEN(current_date, dep_date_of_birth)/12) "Age"
  FROM DEPENDENT d 
  JOIN employee e ON e.emp_no=d.dep_emp_no
 WHERE dep_date_of_birth=(SELECT MIN(DEP_DATE_OF_BIRTH) 
                            FROM DEPENDENT dd 
                           WHERE d.dep_emp_no=dd.dep_emp_no)
  and  exists (select count(dep_emp_no) 
                           from dependent d2 
                           where d.dep_emp_no=d2.dep_emp_no
                           group by dep_emp_no
                           having count(dep_emp_no)>1 );
```

Comment: I get ERROR at line 12:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: I just made another edit. It is untested, but the `exists` must be standalone but then you need to connect. The query is still a bit clumsy and can be even be more improved but I guess you can work out the rest for yourself.

Comment: another, simpler way would be to have `and (select count(*) from dependent d2 where d.dep_emp_no = d2.dep_emp_no) > 1`